# systemd service on shutdown with disk access [backup]

Tags: systemd, backup, btrfs, shutdown, cryptsetup

I'd like to run a little backup script (*btrfs snapshot + transfer to usb*) on system shutdown.

The following service executes perfectly fine on shutdown, but not on reboot as intended:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup on poweroff to external encrypted USB disk.
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 30
TimeoutSec=infinity
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target
```

Where `/usr/bin/sleep 30` will be replaced by the actual backup-script once this service works as intended.

---

But for the backup-script to work properly I need to decrypt an external USB disk with cryptsetup before it is started. This is all handled in the background by a combination of `/etc/crypttab` (`noauto`) and systemd (via `systemd-cryptsetup-generator`), which auto-generates a systemd unit-file `systemd-cryptsetup@<name>.service` that I can reference in the above unit.

But as soon as I add the following requirement to the [unit] section:

```
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
After=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
```

The service is not started anymore during shutdown/poweroff of the system.

Starting the service manually via `systemctl start poweroff-backup.service` works without a problem, so there is no issue with the service-file itself... :-/

---

I **think** the issue is that the `poweroff.target` via `systemd-poweroff.service` requires the `umount.target` which in turn unmounts all devices (including cryptsetup '*mounts*') via a combination of **ConflictedBy=** and **After=** statements for the systemd mount und cryptsetup units.
But adding another requirement towards the `umount.target` does not change anything, eg:

```
Before=umount.target
```

Without any of the additional requirements I can clearly see that the service is always started right after the `umount.target` has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the issue and from that I was able to build a correctly working solution that stills follows the systemd workflow (*for the most part*).

### Issue

The following service, while on first sight looking correct will never be executed:

```
# poweroff-backup.service
[Unit]
Description=Backup on poweroff to external encrypted USB disk.
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target

# This causes the service to be discarded/skipped due to
# a dependency cycle conflict. See below... 
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
After=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
Before=umount.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# Note:  The script executed here needs access to '/', '/tmp' 
# (or Systemd's PrivateTemp) and '/dev/mapper/ext' which is the 
# decrypted USB partition managed by /etc/crypttab and 
# systemd-cryptsetup-generator (as systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service)
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 30
TimeoutSec=infinity
# Note: This does not make any difference
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=poweroff.target
```

The reason why this service will never be started is because there is a dependency cycle issue/conflict between `poweroff.target -[require]-> shutdown.target -[conflicts]-> cryptsetup.target <-[require]- systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service <-[require]- poweroff-backup.service <-[wants]- poweroff.target`, where shutdown.target conflicts cryptsetup.target to ensure all encrypted disks are detached before shutdown (poweroff/reboot) and poweroff-backup.service which needs it to be activated by poweroff.target.

### Solution

Knowing this, the obvious problem lies in my wrong assumption that systemd could somehow avoid this dependency cycle conflict by knowing that poweroff-backup.service is a "*one-shot*" service that can be resolved first by systemd while continuing with the normal shutdown transition once poweroff-backup.service has been activated and transitioned into inactive/done.

So here is a service that uses ExecStop= instead of ExecStart= which allows us to avoid any dependency-cycles, but has some minor caveats:

```
# poweroff-backup.service
[Unit]
Description=Backup external encrypted USB disk on poweroff.
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
After=multi-user.target
After=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo "Waiting for poweroff..."
# Note: We need this, since there is no other way to detect poweroff vs reboot now.
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | /usr/bin/egrep -q 'poweroff.target.*start'
# Note: This should be replaced with your script
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 30
TimeoutSec=infinity
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This works because:

- It prevents the dependency cycle issue caused by shutdown.target, cryptsetup.target and poweroff-backup.service
- The correct working order is still preserved, since systemd ensures that shutdown order is the reverse of the startup order (as given by After= and Before=)

There are only two minor gripes I have with this solution:

- Since the service is started on login, it will also decrypt the external USB disk on login. I would prefer if this would only happen once the actual backup-script is executed while still using the normal systemd After= and Require= order and dependency mechanics. This could be handled by adding the following, but this would mean I'm not using the cryptsetup service for decrypting/detaching the USB disk:

  ```
  ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach ext
  [...]
  ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup detach ext
  ```
- I don't have any way to conditionally execute ExecStop= only on shutdown, by referencing the shutdown.target and have to rely on a little helper command using `systemctl list-jobs`.

**Question:** Has somebody an idea how to improve on those points?

### Full Service File

This is my current service file, which only starts the service once the USB disk is mounted, by attaching (WantedBy=) to the USB device (by its UUID) instead of the multi-user.target:

```
# poweroff-backup.service
[Unit]
Description=Backup external encrypted USB disk on poweroff.
Requires=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
Requires=-.mount
Requires=tmp.mount
After=dev-disk-by\<uuid here>.device
After=systemd-cryptsetup@ext.service
After=-.mount
After=tmp.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo "Waiting for poweroff to trigger snapshot and archive transfer..."
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | /usr/bin/egrep -q 'poweroff.target.*start'
ExecStop=-/usr/local/bin/btrfs-snapshots.sh --device='UUID=<uuid>' @ @boot @home
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/btrfs-archive.sh --source='UUID=<uuid>' --target=/dev/mapper/ext
TimeoutSec=infinity
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-disk-by\<uuid here>.device
```